# how to design the logic behind merging many records into a single record rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merge, associations, rails-activerecord

I have a model called `request`. In this many `request`s can be merged into a single `request`. The user will select a primary and one/many secondary and all the secondary will be merged into the primary. Now what I have done so far is that I have added a boolean column to indicate if a `request` has been merged into another or not. Now I am stumped as to how to handle the association in rails where a model's entity has many other of the same model's entities associated to it. I though of adding a join table with two `request` id's but that seems wrong. What should I do?

Comment: What is the reason behind the downvote? Can the downvoter explain so I can correct in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ancestry**

You'll probably be better looking at the [`ancestry` gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) -

> Ancestry is a gem/plugin that allows the records of a Ruby on Rails
>   ActiveRecord model to be organised as a tree structure (or hierarchy).
>   It uses a single, intuitively formatted database column, using a
>   variation on the materialised path pattern. It exposes all the
>   standard tree structure relations (ancestors, parent, root, children,
>   siblings, descendants) and all of them can be fetched in a single SQL
>   query. Additional features are STI support, scopes, depth caching,
>   depth constraints, easy migration from older plugins/gems, integrity
>   checking, integrity restoration, arrangement of (sub)tree into hashes
>   and different strategies for dealing with orphaned records.

Although not exactly what you're asking for, this basically gives you the ability to "associate" records in the same model, using the `ancestry` column

--

**Requests**

This means that if you have a request which has a `parent` as another request (I.E if you're following chained requests), it will allow you to populate the `ancestry` attribute in your new `request` column, giving you an association

If you have requests with their `ancestry` columns populated, you'll be able to use some of the `ancestry` methods to call the associative objects:

```
@request.children
```

---

**Boolean**

In terms of a `boolean` request - boolean is `1`/`0` (`true` / `false`). You would not be able to associate your requests with *other* requests with a boolean column - you'd have to use some sort of referential attribute (a `foreign_key`)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. Note that I am using the boolean value in order to make the checking of a request is merged or not easy but not otherwise for the merging logic itself.

Comment: Okay thanks for update! Have you looked at the `Ancestry` gem?